# object Promise вместо значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Есть две функции, использующие `async await`:

```
function getAirportViaJson(code) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $.getJSON('/json/airports.travelpayouts.json', function(data){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            if(code == data[i].code)
                resolve(data[i].name_translations.ru);
        });
    });
}

async function getAirportByCode(code) {
    let airport = await getAirportViaJson(code);
    return airport;
}

getAirportByCode('SVO');
```

Функция должна возвращать значение `Шереметьево`, исходя из его IATA-кода `SVO`, но почему-то возвращается `[object Promise]`. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили `async` функцию. Это значит, что возвращает она `promise`. 
Так как она находится на т.н. "верхнем уровне" необходимо `promise` обработать ручками, без `await`
И пожалуйста, **не забывайте что в теле `async` функции должен присутствовать блок `try...catch`, иначе uncaught promise rejection вас ждет**

```js
function getAirportViaJson() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve("123");
  });
}

async function getAirportByCode(code) {
    try {
      let airport = await getAirportViaJson();
      return airport;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
}

getAirportByCode('SVO')
  .then(console.log) // function(res) {console.log(res)}
  .catch(alert);
```

Код работает в последнем `chrome`.

Comment: Почему данный ответ не отмечен "правильным"? Что-то не так?